# How can you Unset the following UpValues?

Tags: function-construction, pattern-matching

This expression is taken from a [talk](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Courseware/377/) given by the late Robby Villegas. The `UpValues` to some symbol `a` is defined below as:

```
ClearAll["a"];
a /: _[___, a, ___] := (Print["a fired"]; Null)
```

Nothing I tried could `Clear` the definitions associated with the symbol. Is there a way to clear the associated UpValues.

Comment: Regardless of the method to solve this problem, I will mention that giving such generic `UpValues` to symbols is outright dangerous. Speaking from experience here, I have tried to use this kind of rules before, and it was invariably biting me later - so I never ended up leaving such constructs in final code in whatever I was doing.

Answer (score 9):

Note that you could clear all of the *Values by using `Clear["a"]` or `ClearAll["a"]`. However, if you only want to clear this particular [`UpValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpValues) you could make use of the fact that [`HoldAllComplete`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldAllComplete) prevents [`UpValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpValues) from firing. So, temporarily give [`TagUnset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TagUnset) this attribute. Here's your [`UpValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpValues) definition:

```
ClearAll["a"];
a /: _[___,a,___] := (Print["a fired"];Null)
```

Give [`TagUnset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TagUnset) the [`HoldAllComplete`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldAllComplete) attribute, and unset the above definition:

```
Internal`InheritedBlock[{TagUnset},
    SetAttributes[TagUnset, HoldAllComplete];
    TagUnset[a, _[___,a,___]]
]
```

Check:

```
UpValues[a]
```

> {}

Comment: Thanks. Very neat.

Answer (score 6):

```
a /: Except[TagUnset, _][___, a, ___] := (Print["a fired"]; Null);

f[a]
(* a fired *)

(* As we can see below, usage of ClearAll does not work *)

ClearAll[a]
(* a fired *)


(* now removing the associated values using the TagUnset Head *)

TagUnset[Unevaluated[a],HoldPattern[Except[TagUnset, _][___, a, ___]]];

f[a]
(* f[a] *)
```

Comment: I think both the Unevaluated and the HoldPattern are unnecessary.

Comment: @Carl .. though unnecessary but I think it is a safe practice